# .iloc and for loop in pandas to add new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

there is a dataframe like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[11, 21], [24, 15], [17, 48], [28, 31], [22, 14]],columns=['A', 'B'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orCYv.jpg)

so  I want to add new column in name "C".  but I want "C" calculate

base on "A" as  "C"[i]="A"[i]-"A"[i-1] formula.

I wrote two kinds method but they did not work.

first method):

```py
for i in (0,5)
    df['c'].iloc[i]=df['A'].iloc[i]- df['A'].iloc[i-1]
print(df)
```

second):

```py
for i in (0,5)
    df.iloc['c',i]=df.iloc['A',i]- df.iloc['A',i-1]
print(df)
```

could someone guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.shift()`:

```
df["C"] = df.A - df.A.shift(1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A   B     C
0  11  21   NaN
1  24  15  13.0
2  17  48  -7.0
3  28  31  11.0
4  22  14  -6.0
```